# How to trace CakePHP's inner workflow

Tags: debugging, cakephp, trace, cakephp-2.0

#### Short description

I'm getting used to CakePHP right now and am wondering about how to get more debug-information about what is happening inside the framework.

#### Let me please explain my situation a little more detailed

As you know CakePHP does a lot for you without putting you into the need to write additional code. One example is the handling of models.
I just created a model User and added validation-rules (no other methods). As described in the API methods like save will just work.
After that I created the needed controller and view to add a new user. When I try to add a user from the view I just receive the flash-message `The user could not be created. Please, try again.` No validation-violations are flashed.

I also did set the debug-level to 2: `Configure::write('debug', 2);` but do not receive any errors. The `error.log` inside \tmp\logs is also empty.

I really do want to learn how to solve those issues in the future.

**So what else can I do to debug / display inner processes of cake?**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you watching/outputting the SQL logs? I assume this is a database/datasource access situation, and it's entirely possible Cake did it's validation right but SQL executed in an unexpected way. SQL doesn't throw an exception when it fails, just a warning (though those should show up in your logs/output), and malformed queries can appear to run correctly without actually saving data.

Comment: Do you mean the executed SQL-statements? Yes they are displayed, but these do only show SELECT-Statements. Anyway I can see that beforeSave() and save() from my model are being executed, but for any reason save() returns false. Do you have any idea how to trace that without implementing my own save()-function?

Comment: I've been doing similar the ugly but simple way, doing things like die($this->data) just before saving to verify the saved data is in the right format, if all the numbers and array indicies check out right and validation is passing you'll need a real trace like in handsoaten 's answer

Comment: There was also a way to catch the insert/update sql statements which is what I was referring to, but since Cake 1.3 I don't recall how to catch those anymore. IT used to be if you die() after calling model->save() you could catch them but I don't know how to call the cake SQL dump inside a controller rather than a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DebugKit is an official plugin that gives you lots of information on the request, queries and variables produced by Cake:

https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

You can also use `trace()` and other methods in the Debugger to show what is being executed in the background:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Espacially debug_kit seems to be a great addition. But unfortunately I still don't see any errors. I can see that `beforeSave()` and `save()` from my model are being executed, but for any reason `save()` returns `false`. Do you have any idea how to trace that without implementing my own `save()`-function?

Comment: `beforeSave()` is a good place to put `pr($this->data); return true;` to check that the array sent to the ORM looks good. You can also pull the actual query being performed out of DebugKit and run it directly on your database, assuming the query is even run.

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP IDE with an integrated debugger. That will allow you to follow execution line by line as it is executed and even inspect variable values as you go. Netbeans is a free one.